# Why are the question on linux not considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

As we already know that Super User is a for computer enthusiasts and power users but we have different sites for Linux questions such as:

1. [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) -  for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Unix-like operating systems
2. [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com) - for Information security professionals (mostly which are related to Linux)
3. [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) - for Ubuntu users (also Linux based OS)
4. [Server fault](https://serverfault.com/) - for system and network administrators (also includes Linux ).

So the question is - 
 Why the questions related to Linux are not migrated to these sites?
Why they are not considered off-topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sites on the Stack Exchange network *do* tend to overlap in scope. It is not the case that a question asked on a more "generalist" site is automatically off-topic on that site once another site comes along that is more specific.

The more specific targeted sites, like AskUbuntu, Unix&Linux, etc. are designed to give users a community that shares a lot in common. This increases the likelihood of better quality, more direct answers. But that doesn't mean that those questions *can't* be asked on Super User anymore.

Generally, my guidelines would be:

1. If you *know of* a StackExchange community that specifically caters to the nature of the problem you're having, then ask your question there.
2. If you don't know of a site that is very "zeroed-in" on the issue you're having, but you can find a generalist site where it's on-topic, like Super User or Stack Overflow, then you can ask it there. If you get an answer that's useful, great! If not, after waiting a week or so for answers, you can request migration to a more specific site.
3. If another user asks a question on a "generalist" site that's clearly more likely to receive better answers on a "specialized" site, we should first attempt to answer it here on the generalist site without reference to the specialized site. If no one knows the answer after a while (a week or two), you can ask the OP if they would like to have it migrated to improve the likelihood of a better answer. Then the SU mods can work with another site's mods, vet the question (to verify that it's on-topic and of good quality), and migrate it if everything looks good.

Answer (score 4):

Because they arn't. We have a wider scope. In one word *[ewoks](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/)*.

*Computers* are our scope, and so those things are not off topic for us